# how to iterate on two subclass models with same for loop?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-model-utils

I want to create a photo sharing website, but i don't know how to iterate over 
this code:

`all_post = Images.objects.all().order_by('-created').select_subclasses()`

my models.py

```
class Images(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='images_created', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    objects = InheritanceManager()

class Postimg(Images):
    user_img= models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)


class Postsms(Images):
    user_message = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    all_post = Images.objects.all().order_by('-created').select_subclasses()
    return render(request, 'copybook/home.html',{ 'all_post':all_post})
```

home.html

```
  {% for foo in all_post %}

      <hr>
     <br> SMS by:  <p>{{ foo.user}}  __  {{ foo.created }}</p> <br>
      <h2>{{ foo.user_message }}</h2>

       <hr>
   <br> IMAGE by:  <p>{{ foo.user}}  __  {{ foo.created }}</p> <br>

   <img src="{{ foo.user_img.url }}"width="250">

  {% endfor %}
```

how do i iterate it in home.html

Comment: What you have should work. What do you see happening and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Does the view that handles uploading an image redirect to the `home` view? Or does it attempt to render the `'copybook/home.html'` template?

Comment: 'copybook/home.html' is my home page.

Comment: Please include the view that handles uploading of a new image.

Comment: e.g Facebook , when someone uploads image or write something,  that will upload on the top of feed page, so i want that happen on my home page , if you please help

Comment: Are you sure they are being created? Are you caching anywhere?

Comment: yes they are created , i can see them on my home page ,,

Comment: when a user upload a images on my website i will show on top of home page , and after some time when a user uploads a message that will show on top of home top .

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me. I don't think your question is explaining what you want/need.

Comment: plz check this question :--   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55841686/django-how-to-iterate-querysets-of-two-subclasses-in-template